# Apple push notification or firebase push notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I just want to know that i used fireabase in my project. Can anyone please guide me which is good for push notifications? Firebase or  Apple Push notification. and I also want some genuine reasons which one is better for User.

Comment: Your question is primarily opinionated. You need to make your question specific. Define "good for notifications".

Answer (score 17):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is originally a platform to send notification for Android. They added an iOS SDK, but using their SDK on iOS means that you are using both FCM and Apple Push notification service:

Push for iOS device => Firebase Cloud Messaging => Apple APNS => Device

If you are only developing an iOS app, it is best to use APNS directly. If you already have all your infrastructure set up for FCM, then you may save you a bit of code by supporting only FCM to address both iOS and Android.

However there is no specific technical benefit doing so.

Comment: There is practical benefit: using only one method is less work than two separate methods for Android / iOS

Answer (score 14):

Some of FCM advantages are

1. Even if user disallow notification you can have notification for your app, if app is running in foreground *(using shouldEstablishDirectChannel)*.
2. Don't need to create dashboard to send notification on device.
3. Notification analytics on FCM Dashboard.
4. Easy to create notification payload structure.
5. App Server side handling is easy, Only one key is required for multiple apps and platform (iOS,Android,Web)

Comment: please accept and upvote answer, if it was your answer, let me know if anything else you need to know

Comment: Can you please tell me why apple push notification is better than firebase. Please give me some strong and valid reasons.

Comment: one of them is, point number 1). even if user disallow notification your app can have notification in foreground, second Notification analytics you can have on FCM dashboard

Answer (score 1):

The maximum notification payload allowed through APNs is 4 KB in iOS 8 and above. It was only 256 bytes operating systems prior to iOS 8. Keep in mind that the notification payload is the sum of notification size and device token.

Through FCM, it is also possible to send messages apart from notifications. FCM describes two different payload sizes for different functions. The maximum notification payload size allowed is 2 KB which is lowest when comparing FCM with APNs and WNS. The maximum message payload size is 4 KB.

WNS is the one that allows highest notification payload among the three, and that is 5 KB.

Answer (score -1):

APNS is much more better in my experience. 
They have much more success and it's easier.
I guess it works better as it's Apple's service.

Comment: If I use Firebase to send notifications, do I need some additional Google libraries in my iOS app or does the operating system display them the same way even if they are sent from FCM? And clicking them launches the app (if on background)?

Why do I need to do this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#add_firebase_to_your_app

Comment: As FCM uses FCM token you will need to add Firebase lib. to get the FCM token.And for retrieve data and etc with Lib would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks, just learned that as well. Firebase seems to be doing a lot of statistics collecting (similar stuff Mixpanel and FB Pixel do), so this seems like Google's plan trying to fetch all possible information from the Internet. I do not want to support this, nor I want to install extra library to make my client larger.