# Push Notification from website to mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to develop a website that will be able to send `push notifications` to a mobile application that would be able to run on both `android` and `iOS`.

For the last couple of years, I am working as a web developer so developing the website is not something that I am worried about, but I have never developed a mobile application before, the mobile app would only receive notifications from the website so the main functionality would be in the website.

Can anyone suggest me what the best approach is and what I have to learn to be able to do this?

Thank you in Regards

Comment: Comparison – Apple Push Notification Service (APNS), Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) , Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and Windows Notification Service (WNS) [here](https://www.hexnode.com/blogs/comparison-apple-push-notification-service-apns-gcm-fcm-wns/) you may find this of interest.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525917/apple-push-notification-or-firebase-push-notifications) and [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-build-my-own-push-notification-service) can throw some light on what is your best way forward.

Answer (score 6):

I guess, you have 2 options.

- You can either use Firebase FCM
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
- or use a third party which is called OneSignal
  https://onesignal.com/.

If you are looking for an easier way then I recommend using OneSignal instead. You just need to define API Key in your build.gradle and initialize OneSignal in onCreate().

Answer (score 2):

The best approach, in my opinion, would be to use firebase (https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/). I think it is better because it is a unique framework for both ios and android and you don't need to worry about the user device when sending the message(you could build an interface in your backend code to handle this but why doing something that already exists and it is free).
The flow is something like this:

1. on the first start the app(either ios or android) must send its firebase ID to your server so that you can store it (simple http request will od it) and set up a listener for the incoming push messages
2. when you need to send a push message all you need to do is an http request and you can trigger it with js from your website. The request will contain data such as the firebase id of the receiving device(which you have previously stored)

Firebase Cloud Messaging also have some really nice features like upstream messages(push messages from the device to the server, but you need an xmpp server to listen for them) and topics to send the same notification to many users at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to create a node server where the website would be running on and then use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications

EDIT: FCM supports both Android and iOS

Comment: Can you please give me some more details? What would you use for the node server?